# Are all threads halted when one of them receives a signal and none of them block it?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, signals

I'm running a multithreaded application written in C on Linux.

To stop execution I send `SIGINT` and from the signal handler call a number of cleanup routines and, finally, call `exit(0)`.

Are the other threads still running or may run (context switch) while the handler executes the cleanup routines?

Comment: You do not want to call `exit()` fro within a signal-handler as it is not guarenteed to by asynch-signal safe. Call `_exit()` instead. Or even better do not end the program from the signal-handler at all, but perform a gracefull shutdown, by having all threads end normally. For reference: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Handling a signal does not cause the suspension of other threads during execution of the signal handler. Moreover, it's generally not safe to call most functions you would need for cleanup (including even `exit`!) from a signal handler unless you can ensure that it does not interrupt an async-signal-unsafe function.

What you should do is simply store the fact that `SIGINT` was received in some async-signal-safe manner and have the program act on that condition as part of its normal flow of execution, outside the signal handler. Then you can properly synchronize with other threads (using mutexes, condition variables, etc.) to achieve a proper, safe shutdown. The ideal method is not to even install a signal handler, but instead block all signals and have a dedicated signal-handling thread calling `sigwaitinfo` in a loop to accept signals.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a signal is delivered to *one* thread, chosen in an unspecified way. Only threads that aren't blocking the signal are considered, though; if all threads block the signal, it remains queued up until one thread unblocks it.

(So if you make *all* threads block the signal, you can use the signal as a deterministic, inter-process synchronization mechanism, e.g. using `sigwait`.)

Comment: But may the others run if they don't block the signal, while the one that received the signal is handling it? Because I have a log, and I have prints caused by different threads after the signal handler prints "Exit".

Comment: Yes, threads that don't receive signals don't do anything special. They don't know that another thread has received a signal.

Comment: @R.. Post another answer :-)